# Python: Displaying values alongside a bar in a bar graph. Values greater than the actual value is getting displayed

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a grouped bar graph in which I display the corresponding value alongside the bar. Currently, what my code does is, it displays the value alongside the bar, which is 1 greater than the actual value. What changes do I need to make in my code such that it displays the actual value alongside the bars?

[image]

```
# importing package
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
  
# create data
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 10, 20, 10, 30], ['B', 20, 25, 15, 25], ['C', 12, 15, 19, 6],
                   ['D', 10, 29, 13, 19]],
                  columns=['Team', 'Round 1', 'Round 2', 'Round 3', 'Round 4'])
# view data
print(df)


  
# plot grouped bar chart
ax=df.plot.barh(x='Team',        
        stacked=False,
        log=True,
        figsize=(12, 7),
        title='Grouped Bar Graph with dataframe')

for c in ax.containers:     
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='edge')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation `help(ax.bar_label)` it is hinted that `label_type="edge"` and `label_type="center"` shows different values. One way to fix that is to pass our labels, like this:

```
for c in ax.containers:
    labels = c.datavalues.astype(str)
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='edge', labels=labels)
```

Comment: Can you please tell how to limit the data to two decimal places in case we have any points on the RHS of the decimal point.

Comment: You can format labels before passing them to `ax.bar_label`. Something like this: `labels = ["%.2f" % t if isinstance(t, float) else "%s" % t for t in c.datavalues]`

Comment: Hi, can you please help me with this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/72229250/19024581